# Magento cache issue in multi store

Tags: magento, caching, magento-1.9

I have multi store set up in Magneto extension,during development phase I disabled cache but now my development is over and I want to enable cache to increase the performance of my site.But as I enabled cache from Admin my website show abnormal behavior i.e.,show blank screen in Admin and in front end or not showing product in category page.This is the two case I found as i Enabled cache.

Please tell me how to enable cache without disturb my all site.

Comment: After debugging I found that product is invisible due to "Blocks HTML output" Cache.

Answer (score 0):

Above issue is solve by:-
You may be using an alternative cache backend, in such case, using the Flush Cache Storage button should be sufficient to empty the cache contents and then enable cache of "Blocks HTML output".

Answer (score 0):

Your cache blocks might not be have a store ID as a key element.

This might result in cache getting shared and resulting in wrong blocks being displayed.

Comment: How can i add store Id to my cache block,to fix this issue.